# How can I pass dictionary to a function in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to pass dictionary to a function in python but it shows me error.

```
class stud:
    def method(**arg):
        print(arg)

dict1 = {1:"abc",2:"xyz"}
a = stud()
a.method(dict1)
```

This raises the following error:

```
>>> a.method(dict1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: method() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given
```

Can you tell me were I goes wrong or the right way to pass dictionary to a function?

Answer (score 1):

As @Bit mentions, if `method` is *not* a static method. You need to add a `self` parameter.

There are two options here:

- you use a **normal parameter in the method**:

```
class stud:

    def method(self,arg):  # normal parameter
        print(arg)
```

- you **pass the dictionary as named parameters** in the call:

```
class stud:

    def method(self,**arg):  # normal parameter
        print(arg)

    a.method(**dict1)
```

Personally I would go with the first one, since it is:

1. more efficient: you pass only a reference to the dictionary; and
2. if you want to alter the original dictionary, that is still possible.

Comment: Isn't the problem here that the signature of `method` doesn't include `self`?

Comment: @Digres: of course you should include it above 3.5. The data model is not changed. Only for static methods (and `cls` for class methods), there is no self.